# Trying to delete a row from my database using a button

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete a row from my database when I click on the reject button. However, at the moment it's not actually doing anything.

the PHP for the delete query is;

```
require_once('my_connect.php');

$requestid = $_GET["requestid"];
$delete_query = "Delete from loanrequests where requestid='$requestid'";

$delete_result = mysqli_query($connection, $delete_query);

if ($delete_result) :
        header ('location: requests.php?confirm=Loan request rejected');
    else:
        echo "<b>Didnt work error</b>";
        echo mysqli_error($connection);
endif;
```

It's working when I use the following within a table:

```
 $table.= "<td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To  Delete This User?')\" href=deleterequest.php?requestid=$requestid><img src=\"delete.png\">";
```

but can't make it work to delete on the click of my button using ;

```
<input type="submit" name="rejectloan" value="Reject Loan" onClick="window.location.href='deleterequest.php'">
```

Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong? I know my `deleterequest.php` page is correct as it is working one way, but it's not working in the way I'm hoping to use it.

Comment: Show full code of that table. where form tag is used. Something fishy there.

Answer (score 0):

In the method that is working, you are passing a variable to the URL: deleterequest.php?requestid=$requested.
In the method that is not working, you are not:
window.location.href='deleterequest.php'

This line: $requestid = $_GET["requestid"];
Is pulling the value of the id from the URL. You are not passing that value to the URL, so you are most likely getting a null or undeclared value.

You are using the id to delete a specific record. The second method doesn't include an id. Most likely, it is a null value, which would almost certainly delete nothing in the database. You should include the id of the record to be deleted in the URL. That would solve the problem.

Comment: i understand that is where the issue may be. Would i need to pass the variable to the url inside php tags or is there a way to do so within the html form?

Comment: window.location.href='deleterequest.php?requestid=<?php $requested ?>' would probably work. It has been a little while since I've used PHP, though, so my syntax may be off. The root of your problem was the omission of the id in the URL. Now that you have that, there are multiple ways to solve the problem. One of which you have identified, which I am posting an example of here.